# equality in proof that atoms are in $H^p$

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The following equality on page 121 of Grafakos' *Modern Fourier Analysis* is escaping me:
$$\int\limits_Q A(y) \left[\Psi(2^jx - 2^jy) - \sum\limits_{|\beta|\leq k-1} \frac{\partial^\beta\Psi(2^jx)}{\beta!}(-2^jy)^\beta \right] \; dy = \int\limits_Q A(y) \left[ \sum\limits_{|\beta|=k} \frac{\partial^\beta\Psi(2^jx - 2^j\theta y)}{\beta!}(-2^jy)^\beta \right] \; dy$$.

Above, $A$ is an $L^q$-atom for $H^1$, $\Psi$ is radial Schwartz function compactly supported away from the origin in frequency (used in Littlewood-Paley decomp.), $Q$ is a cube centered at the origin containing the support of $A$, and $\theta$ is (apparently) any constant in $[0,1]$.

If anyone could provide any insight as to why this is true, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: Should be a beta, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Surely this is Taylor's theorem: $\Psi$ minus a Taylor polynomial equals (some form of) the remainder...